# Использование справочников значений свойств объектов в приложении с EF Core Code First

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-core

Приложение на C# WPF c использованием паттерна MVVM. Для взаимодействия с базой данных предполагается использовать EF Core. В некоторых случаях пользователи при заполнении сведений о доменных объектах должны использовать значения из справочников (от небольших, до 10 записей, в одних случаях, до имеющих сотни значений в других), т.е. по сути это lookup tables. Каков в этом случае правильный подход к построению структуры БД? Если использовать EF по типу Code First, то значения каждого справочника должны быть представлены своим POCO со ссылкой на него в основном объекте? Возможно, есть более правильный подход к такой задаче?

Comment: `Если использовать EF по типу Code First, то значения каждого справочника должны быть представлены своим POCO` разве? Я не пробовал, но в теории можно попробовать сделать 1 класс и засунуть несколько свойств в контекст с типом этого класса и поглядеть, что сгенерится. PS погуглил, позоду надо несколько классов

Comment: В принципе, если вы уверены, что все справочники будут однотипными (ключ - значение, при этом типы одинаковые, допустим "всегда строка"), то можно вынести все однотипные лукапы в одну таблицу, а всё индивидуальное выносить отдельно по принципу "одна таблица - один справочник". Но если очень хочется создать какой-нибудь конструктор таблиц - оооо, ну что ж, можно и создать, просто не факт, что это сэкономит усилия на разработку+поддержку.

Comment: имхо, проще сделать базовый класс для словарей и нафигарить от него столько классов-словарей, сколько надо

Comment: Спасибо за советы. Главное понял, что мои предположения не идут вразрез с представлениями тех, у кого больше опыта. Мне было важно это понять, потому что решение выглядит не особо изящным, так что я беспокоился, что что-то сильно упустил.